# @Transactional not starting transactions with Spring Boot 3 / Hibernate 6

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-orm

I am currently migrating to Spring Boot 3 / Hibernate 6.
Hibernate is correctly parsing all the entities and repos, connecting to the database, etc...

However, it seems @Transactional is not starting transactions correctly.

Small example:

```
@Component
public class Test {

  @Autowired
  private EntityManagerFactory entityManager;

  @Transactional
  public void test() {
    Session s = entityManager.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).getCurrentSession();
    s.createQuery("FROM sometable").list();
  }
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Calling method 'createQuery' is not valid without an active transaction (Current status: NOT_ACTIVE)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:341)
```

Relevant Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.somepackage")
@EntityScan(basePackages="com.somepackage")
public class TransactionConfig {
...
}
```

session context class in application.properties

```
...
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=thread
...
```

If I remove the above setting of session_content_class=thread,
I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: No CurrentSessionContext configured
```

Edit 1:

The below still results in the same error "is not valid without an active transaction"

```
  @PersistenceUnit
  private EntityManagerFactory entityManager;
```

Edit 2:

If I do not unwrap a session and just call a class with extends extends JpaRepository, it works... but it creates a new transaction and ignores the parent @Transaction

Comment: Try modifying your `@Autowired
  private EntityManagerFactory` into `@PersistenceUnit  private EntityManagerFactory`

Comment: Same error Calling method 'createQuery' is not valid without an active transaction (Current status: NOT_ACTIVE)

Comment: Have you tried changing to @PersistenceUnit and removing the current_session_context_class config at the same time to test it? If that doesn't work you can try to use `@PersistenceContext private EntityManager em`

Comment: Removing current_session_context and keeping```@PeristenceUnit``` causes ```No CurrentSessionContext configured```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix was the following:

```
    @PersistenceContext 
    private EntityManager entityManager;
```

and to unwrap:

```
    Session s = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
```